# Qml Qt Quick Control 2: Scale font size without binding loop

Tags: qt, qml, qtquickcontrols2

I want to scale the font size of a `Label` like this:

```
Label {
    font.size: font.size*0.8
}
```

Of course this creates a binding loop. Is there a way to do this without creating a hidden `Label` element?

```
Label {
    id: hiddenLabel
}

Label {
    font.size: hiddenLabel.font.size*0.8
}
```

Scaling the whole label is not optimal because the text quality decreases:

```
Label {
    scale: 0.8
}
```

Regards,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In addition to the other options already mentioned, there's also [`Qt.application.font`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#application-prop):

```
Label {
    font.pixelSize: Qt.application.font.pixelSize * 0.8
}
```

> This read-only property holds the default application font as returned by `QGuiApplication::font()`.

The [commit message for the change](https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/148092/) mentions other options that were considered at the time:

> - "`<h3>Large text</h3>`" - adds extra space below the text since it's a HTML element, so not really useful if you want a decent layout.
> - Hard-coding a pixel size. Works OK when used in combination with Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling, and so long as you guess the correct size
>     that works for each device/display you're targeting. Doesn't work
>     without setting Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling.
> - Using FontMetrics/TextMetrics. Works fine, but is a bit verbose.
> - Use an empty Text element. Creates an unnecessary item. Was superseded by FontMetrics/TextMetrics.
> - defaultPixelSize/implicitPixelSize and defaultPointSize/implicitPointSize. There are already font-related
>     properties outside of the font grouped property, so this wouldn't be
>     out of place, but the API is already quite large.

If you really need to base the font size on the particular control that you're using, the only guaranteed way is to create an "empty"/"default-constructed" instance of that control:

```
Button {
    id: dummyButton
}

Button {
    font.pixelSize: dummyButton.font.pixelSize * 0.8
}
```

This is because each style has different font sizes for different types of controls. See the [Material style's theme code](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols2.git/tree/src/imports/controls/material/qquickmaterialtheme.cpp#n67), for example.

Answer (score 1):

You might use an assignment instead of a binding, by setting the fontsize in `Component.onCompleted`

```
Label {
    text: 'Þetta reddast'
    Component.onCompleted: font.pixelSize *= 0.8
}
```

This has the negative side effect that the text is layed out twice: Once for the larger size and then again with the smaller size.

I would propably define a set of `fonts` with the right sizes in a `style.qml singleton` as [***proposed here***](https://wiki.qt.io/Qml_Styling). There you can use the applications default font metrics to calculate relative sizes initally, so you don't have to bother later.

Answer (score 0):

```
FontMetrics {
    id: fontMetrics
}

Label {
    font.size: fontMetrics.font.size * 0.8
}
```

Comment: Hi, in the context of `Controls` this won't give you reliable results, as e.g, you might use an `ApplicationWindow` as root object and set a font size there.This would be propagated to the `Label` but not to the non-control `FontMetrics`. Therefore the default font size of the `Label` and of the `FontMetrics` are not necessary the same - and with this the 0.8th factor of it neither. See [**here**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-control.html#font-prop)

Comment: @derM that's useful if it's not tied to a root element. Are there any non-root elements that can do that? About the `FontMetrics`: I like defining everything (even the non-text stuff) relative to it.

Comment: You could use the attached [`ApplicationWindow`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-applicationwindow.html#window-attached-prop) property to get the font in the case that @derM refers to, and then set that on `fontMetrics`. E.g.: `font: ApplicationWindow.window.font` Although different controls have different default sizes, so this only works for certain controls: http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols2.git/tree/src/imports/controls/material/qquickmaterialtheme.cpp#n67

Comment: @Velkan: Yes indeed. e.g. you might have a `ApplicationWindow` with font.pixelSize: 30, which contains a `Page` with `font.pixelSize: 100` which then contains the `Label`. The Label gets the `font.pixelSize: 100` propagated by the `Page`. This implies that the attatched property `ApplicationWindow` would not work either.

Comment: AFAIK there is no attatched property for all the controls, similar to the `ApplicationWindow`, so there is no other reliable way to do this, other than using the `Component.onCompleted`-method, or you define some standard font sizes (e.g. in a style singleton class) that you can make relative to the default size, as explained by @Mitch. Maybe the QTies will introduce a more general attatched property to have access to this inheritance tree.

Comment: Please read [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to define a global property in `main.qml`, instead of defining text size in every element separately.
For this purpose define a property in `main.qml` like this:

```
readonly property Item fontCenter: Item {
    property real heading1PointSize: 21
    property real heading2PointSize: 18
    property real bodyPointSize: 12
}
```

and use it anywhere as this:

```
Text {
    text: "sample body text"
    font { pointSize: fontCenter.bodyPointSize }
}
```

also in case of your question, you can set a property value based on another one:

```
readonly property Item fontCenter: Item {
    property real bodyPointSize: 12
    property real heading1PointSize: bodyPointSize * 2.0
    property real heading2PointSize: bodyPointSize * 1.8
}
```

or for an special case use as follow:

```
Button {
    text: "Special Offer!"
    font { pointSize: fontCenter.bodyPointSize * 1.3 }
}
```